# "ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack" while using enumerate()

Tags: python, python-2.7, valueerror

I'm trying to iterate through indices and corresponding elements of an array consisting of pairs of arrays by using `zip()` and `enumerate()` but I get the following error:

```
a_1 = [1, 2, 3]
a_2 = [11, 22, 33]
a_3 = [111, 222, 333]


b_1 = [5, 6, 7]
b_2 = [55, 66, 77]
b_3 = [555, 666, 777]

for k in range(1, 10):
    for index, a, b in enumerate(zip([a_1, a_2, a_3],
    [b_1, b_2, b_3])):
        print index, a, b
```

But I'm getting the following error regarding the first line:

```
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enumerate` returns two-tuples, but because you enumerate a zip (which in your case also returns two-tuples), the second element of the original two-tuple is also a two-tuple. You have to unpack the outer tuple first, then the inner tuple:

```
for index, (a, b) in enumerate(zip([a_1, a_2, a_3],
    [b_1, b_2, b_3])):
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tuples are structured as `(index, (a, b))`, not `(index, a, b)`. You need to unpack them like that.

```
for index, (a, b) in ...
```